# Will Google Developer Console accept an app created in a different package with same name as the old one for an update?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, package, google-developers-console

to clarify my question, and What I'm trying to do. I have an app at google play and it has been a very long time since I did update for it. What I want is to create a new project with same package name as my app in Google Play. However, I'm not sure if it will get accept by Google Developer Console, since I changed the original package.

Thank you in advance,

P.S. I know that can do the update within the original project but I don't want to because my last update was in 2015 so you could imagine what am talking about :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Name doesn't matter you should not upload the app with old package name, if you do so, it should match the same SHA-1.